# How to adjust logit function's input domain?

Tags: probability, functions, logarithms, transformation, curves

- on the right is the typical S-curve called **expit function** (or sigmoidal logistic function)
- on the left is the **logit function** based on log-odds, which is the inverse of the above

[image]

Now consider for the **left graph**, that the **x-axis** admits for input a statistical measure $P\in [-1, 1]$ instead of the $P\in [0,1]$ shown in the picture, so that a new origin of $x=0$ cuts through the middle of the curve in the left graph, instead of the current $x=0.5$.

How must the logit function be altered to be able to admit such an input domain for the x-axis, but still retain the same curve and same $\mathbb{R}$-ranged output for the y-axis currently shown?

Comment: I didn't understand it properly, @develartist , could you explain it to me a bit more clearly ? (or at least confirm this : are you trying to alter the logit function's domain to $[0,1]$ ?)

Comment: the logit function's input domain is already $[0,1]$. how can it be adjusted to admit an input whose domain is $[-1,1]$?

Comment: Hmm...... sounds good...

Comment: @develartist, maybe you must alter any part of the function to make it fit into the domain you want ?

Comment: what do you mean

Comment: I mean, either alter the denominator part or the numerator part of the function and observe the changes that come up. According to that, you may tune it to the domain you want.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion but looking for a less arbitrary answer. are you aware of any logit or expit function tuning or transformations?

Comment: I understand that, but as a 15-year old, I only told you what I can do :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to

- horizontally scale by a factor of $2$, then
- shift left by $1$.

(See [this random Google result](https://www.varsitytutors.com/hotmath/hotmath_help/topics/transformations-of-graphs) for more on graph transformations.)  The first step takes the domain to $[0,2]$, the second, to $[-1,1]$.

So we replace $P$ with $\frac{1}{2}(P- -1) = \frac{P+1}{2}$ everywhere it appears.
$$  \ln \left( \frac{\frac{P+1}{2}}{1-\frac{P+1}{2}} \right) $$
Of course, this simplifies to
$$  \ln \left( \frac{1+P}{1-P} \right) \text{.}  $$

Comment: I love that answer !

Comment: any intuitive reason for the horizontal scaling of 2. and for the combination of both steps together?

Comment: @develarist : You want the domain to double in width, so scale by $2$.  Afterwards, the domain is $[0,2]$, as mentioned, so you must shift it to be centered.  The two steps are *not* combined -- the scaling is the pre-factor of $1/2$.  The shift is effected by the $-1$.  This is the sequence of operations: scale, then shift.

Answer (score 0):

Unless I'm missing something, $log(\frac{1+P}{1-P})$ is what you're looking for your new variable $P$